Nested fields not getting received on Google Pub/Sub
Since I'm learning the Google Pub/Sub library I've set up a local instance of the Pub/Sub and created 2 apps: 1 to send a message and one to receive it. So far so good,I've managed to set up the subscriptions and topics and I receive the messages, but there's an issue that I noticed. I tried to send a message with nested struct fields but I don't reveive them. This is my code:
Sender:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

type Payload struct {
    ID   string
    Type string
    Name string
    Image
    Thumbnail
}

type Image struct {
    URL    string
    Width  string
    Height string
}

type Thumbnail struct {
    URL    string
    Width  string
    Height string
}

func main() {
    godotenv.Load(".env")

    w := os.Stdout
    projectID := os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID")
    topicID := os.Getenv("TOPIC_ID")
    message := Payload{
        ID:   "1",
        Type: "image",
        Name: "Image 1",
        Image: Image{
            URL:    "https://example.com/image1",
            Width:  "100",
            Height: "100",
        },
        Thumbnail: Thumbnail{
            URL:    "https://example.com/image1/thumb",
            Width:  "50",
            Height: "50",
        },
    }

    if err := publish(w, projectID, topicID, message); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Failed to publish: %v", err)
    }
}

func publish(w io.Writer, projectID, topicID string, msg Payload) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("create new client: %w", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    t := client.Topic(topicID)

    payload, err := json.Marshal(msg)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("marshal payload: %w", err)
    }

    result := t.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
        Data: payload,
    })

    id, err := result.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("pubsub: result.Get: %w", err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Published a message; msg ID: %v\n", id)
    return nil
}

Receiver:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

type Payload struct {
    ID   string
    Type string
    Name string
    Image
    Thumbnail
}

type Image struct {
    URL    string
    Width  string
    Height string
}

type Thumbnail struct {
    URL    string
    Width  string
    Height string
}

func main() {
    projectID := os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID")
    subscriptionID := os.Getenv("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")

    if err := readMessages(projectID, subscriptionID); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("read message: %v", err)
    }
}

func readMessages(projectID, subscriptionID string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("create new client: %w", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    sub := client.Subscription(subscriptionID)

    err = sub.Receive(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context, m *pubsub.Message) {
        result := Payload{}
        message := m.Data

        if err := json.Unmarshal(message, &result); err != nil {
            log.Printf("unmarshal message: %v", err)
            m.Nack()
            return
        }

        log.Printf("get message: %s", m.Data)
        m.Ack()
    })

    if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, context.Canceled) {
        return fmt.Errorf("receive message: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}

Result from the receiver is: Got message: {"ID":"1","Type":"image","Name":"Image 1"}
My question is why am I not receiving the nested fields?

Interesting. You're actually "embedding" Image and Thumbnail into Payload. Does the behavior change if you nest the structs by changing both definitions (better to share these rather than duplicate) of Payload to be type Payload struct { ID string; Type string; Name string; Image Image; Thumbnail Thumbnail; }?

Found the issue. The JSON tags were missing on the structs. Now the struct looks like this:
type Payload struct {
    ID        string    `json:"ID"`
    Type      string    `json:"Type"`
    Name      string    `json:"Name"`
    Image     Image     `json:"Image"`
    Thumbnail Thumbnail `json:"Thumbnail"`
}

type Image struct {
    URL    string `json:"URL"`
    Width  string `json:"Width"`
    Height string `json:"Height"`
}

type Thumbnail struct {
    URL    string `json:"URL"`
    Width  string `json:"Width"`
    Height string `json:"Height"`
}

And the result looks like this:
Got message: {"ID":"1","Type":"image","Name":"Image 1","Image":{"URL":"https://example.com/image1","Width":"100","Height":"100"},"Thumbnail":{"URL":"https://example.com/image1/thumb","Width":"50","Height":"50"}}

